# parse html body fragment in lxml

Tags: python, html, lxml, lxml.html, pyquery

I'm trying to parse a fragment of html:

```
<body><h1>title</h1><img src=""></body>
```

I use `lxml.html.fromstring`. And it is driving me insane because it keeps stripping the `<body>` tag of my fragments:

```
 > lxml.html.fromstring('<html><h1>a</h1></html>').tag
 'html'
 > lxml.html.fromstring('<div><h1>a</h1></div>').tag
 'div'
 > lxml.html.fromstring('<body><h1>a</h1></body>').tag
 'h1'
```

I've also tried the `document_fromstring`, `fragment_fromstring`, `clean_html` with `page_structure=False`, etc... nothing works.

I need to use lxml, since I'm passing the html fragment to PyQuery.

I just want lxml to not mess with my html fragment. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.fragment_fromstring()` removes the `<html>` tag as well; basically, whenever you do *not* have a HTML document (with a `<html>` top-level element and/or a doctype), `.fromstring()` falls back to `.fragment_fromstring()` and that method removes both the `<html>` and the `<body>` tags, always.

The work-around is to tell `.fragment_fromstring()` to give you a `<body>` *parent* tag:

```
>>> lxml.html.fragment_fromstring('<body><h1>a</h1></body>', create_parent='body')
<Element body at 0x10d06fbf0>
```

This does not preserve any attributes on the original `<body>` tag.

Another work-around is to use the `.document_fromstring()` method, which will wrap your document in a `<html>` tag, which you then can remove again:

```
>>> lxml.html.document_fromstring('<body><h1>a</h1></body>')[0]
<Element body at 0x10d06fcb0>
```

This *does* preserve attributes on the `<body>`:

```
>>> lxml.html.document_fromstring('<body class="foo"><h1>a</h1></body>')[0].attrib
{'class': 'foo'}
```

Using the `.document_fromstring()` function on your first example gives:

```
>>> body = lxml.html.document_fromstring('<body><h1>title</h1><img src=""></body>')[0]
>>> lxml.html.tostring(body)
'<body><h1>title</h1><img src=""></body>'
```

If you only want to do this if there is *no* HTML tag, do what `lxml.html.fromstring()` does and test for a full document:

```
htmltest = lxml.html._looks_like_full_html_bytes if isinstance(inputtext, str) else lxml.html._looks_like_full_html_unicode
if htmltest(inputtext):
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(inputtext)
else:
    tree = lxml.html.document_fromstring(inputtext)[0]
```

Comment: Martijn, the solution seems good. The problem with it is that if the fragment actually starts with `<html>`, you will end up losing it, right?

Comment: @fserb: indeed. You could use the same test `lxml.html` uses; the `lxml.html._looks_like_full_html_bytes()` and `lxml.html._looks_like_full_html_unicode()` objects are callables (the `.match()` functions of regular expressions, results of `re.compile()`) that test the input text to see if there is a `html` element or a doctype. If these do not return `None` (one is picked based on the input type) then do not retrieve the body element using indexing perhaps?