# lxml.html ignoring body class attributes

Tags: iframe, html-parsing, lxml, lxml.html

I am using lxml.html for parsing html content. But I don't understand why lxml is dropping "body" tag attributes. 
Tried using both lxml.html.parse and lxml.html.document_fromstring as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498805/parse-html-body-fragment-in-lxml)

But still it is not working.

Example html string:-

`<html class="hello"> <head> <iframe src="index.html"></iframe> </head> <body class="foo"><h1>a</h1></body> </html>`

Does anyone else also faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly too late to help, but I've run into a similar issue with the same underlying parser (lxml uses libxml2, which I am using directly).  I believe the problem is that <iframe>s cannot appear in the <head> of the document.  When libxml2 sees one there, it attempts to continue parsing by implicitly closing the <head> and starting a <body>.  This implicitly created <body> is then confusing you as it does not have the class in your actual <body> tag.  In fact I think your actual <body> will not appear in the parsed model at all.